# In gvim, how do I get 4 splits into 2x2 layout

Tags: gvim

I have 4 splits in gvim, with 1 on the left, and 3 on the right.  I'd like to get them into a 2x2 tile arrangement.

I can't figure out a way to take a window that spans the screen (horz or vert) and shrink it to tile next to an existing item.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is possible by moving windows, but if you're willing to close/reopen:

**From your current configuration:**

> - Close one of the files on the right (:wq)
> - Move to left window - Ctrl+W then left-arrow
> - :split to reopen file closed from right

**From start:**

> - Open first file (upper-left)
> - :vsplit to second file (upper-right)
> - :split to third file (lower-left)
> - Ctrl+W then right-arrow to toggle to second file
> - :split to fourth file (lower-right)